# Angular how to delete a row in mat table?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, mat-table

I can't use `*ngFor` in my angular mat table, or I just don't have the knowledge for that. I would really appreciate it if anyone can help me out?

I want to delete a row within an array for example with a button and then list it on my table, but it just doesn't work. Therefore I want to use `*ngFor` to display the table data, but if I click that `ADD` button it adds another row without data inside.

[image]

This is what I got so far:

angular-table.component.html

```
<table mat-table *ngFor="let item of data" class="mat-elevation-z8" matSort>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="title">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Title</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef> {{item.title}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="id" id="id">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>ID</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef> {{item.id}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="delete">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Test</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef> 
            <mat-icon (click)="removeCart(i)" class="removeCart">close</mat-icon>
        </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>

<button (click)="ADD1()">Add1</button>
<button (click)="ADD2()">Add2</button>
```

angular-table.component.ts

```
export class AngularTableComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  amount: number;
  data: any = [];
  id: number = 2;
  title: string = 'test';

  displayedColumns: string[] = ['title', 'id', 'delete'];


  ADD1(){
    const id = this.id;
    const title = this.title;

    const newData = {
      id,
      title
    }
    this.data.push(newData);
    console.log(this.data);
   }


  ADD2(){
    const id = this.id = 7;
    const title = this.title = "Hello";

    const newData = {
      id,
      title
    }
    this.data.push(newData);
    console.log(this.data);
   }


  removeCart(index: number){
    this.data.splice(index, 1);
  }
}
```

I made a StackBlitz, but sadly it doesn't work I couldn't get it to work to import the modules, I tried for very long. https://stackblitz.com/edit/add-angular-material-o2pu6c?file=src%2Fmain.ts

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First,** at `<table mat-table *ngFor="let item of data"`, it will repeat the table with header all the time. It won't show the data.

**So,** you better use `MatTableDataSource`.

```
dataSource: MatTableDataSource<any> = new MatTableDataSource<any>([]);
```

**Then,** you can assign your data to the `dataSource`'s `data`.

```
this.dataSource.data = this.data;
```

**Now,** your table will be like this:

```
<table mat-table class="mat-elevation-z8" [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>
```

**And,** your column definitions will be like this:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="title">
     <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Title</th>
     <td mat-cell *matCellDef> {{item.title}} </td>
</ng-container>
```

**Since,** you want to delete a row, you need a button and index of the row to delete the row.

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="delete">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Test</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let i = index"> 
        <button mat-icon-button class="removeCart" (click)="removeCart(i)" >
           <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
        </button>
    </td>
</ng-container>
```

**Working demo** at [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wnrmrw?file=src/app/table-basic-example.html).

Answer (score 1):

in your "angular-table.component.html" you add a button in a row and to get the id;

```
<table mat-table *ngFor="let item of data" class="mat-elevation-z8" matSort>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="title">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Title</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef> {{item.title}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="id" id="id">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>ID</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef> {{item.id}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="delete">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Test</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef> 
            <mat-icon (click)="removeCart(i)" class="removeCart">close</mat-icon>
        </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>

                <div class="example-element-description">
                  <button
                    mat-raised-button
                    color="warn"
                    (click)="handelDelete(item.id)"
                  >
                    Delete
                  </button>
                </div>
</table>

<button (click)="ADD1()">Add1</button>
<button (click)="ADD2()">Add2</button>
```

In your angular-table.component.ts, add the method to remove the element form data[] and refresh the table data.

```
export class AngularTableComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  // remove :void type
  // refrech the data with OnInit
 this.data = this.data
  }

  amount: number;
  data: any = [];
  id: number = 2;
  title: string = 'test';

  displayedColumns: string[] = ['title', 'id', 'delete'];

constructor() { }


  ADD1(){
    const id = this.id;
    const title = this.title;

    const newData = {
      id,
      title
    }
    this.data.push(newData);
    console.log(this.data);
   }


  ADD2(){
    const id = this.id = 7;
    const title = this.title = "Hello";

    const newData = {
      id,
      title
    }
    this.data.push(newData);
    console.log(this.data);
   }

handelDelete(pId) {
// to delete the element by id
this.data = this.data.filter(element => element == pId);
  }


  removeCart(index: number){
    this.data.splice(index, 1);
  }
}
```